# Class library does not recognize CommandManager class

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, command, class-library

I'm developing WPF applications and I want to reuse my classes that are the same in all those applications so I can add them as a reference.

In my case I have a class for my Commands:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    #region Fields

    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    #endregion // Fields

    #region Constructors

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {

    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }
    #endregion // Constructors

    #region ICommand Members

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    #endregion // ICommand Members
}
```

This works perfect in my application, but when I want to make a class library which I just want to add as a reference in my project, visual studio can't build because "**CommandManager** does not exists in the current context". In my usings I have the following (which should be enough)

```
 using System;
 using System.Windows.Input;
```

Any ideas why I can't do this in a "class library project" ?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Go to the "References" part of your class library and select "Add Reference".  Look for an assembly called "PresentationCore" and add it.

Then in your class file add the using statement `using System.Windows.Input;`

You will then be able to access the CommandManager as you expect.

Just adding:  lots of guys when they go to create a class library, they select "WPF Custom Control Library" and then erase the "Class1.cs" file.  It's a shortcut that automatically adds the right namespaces to your library.  Whether it's a good or bad shortcut is anybody's call, but I use it all the time.