# CommandManager not found Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm doing a Windows Phone app and I'm trying to add en event to CommandManager.RequerySuggest. But it does not compile telling me that CommandManager does not exist. I have put the reference System.Windows.Input.
Thanks for the help.

Ps:I may I created a Silverlight app, I dont remember lol and I am on vs2013.

Edit: Part of the code:

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add
        {
            if (this.canExecute != null)
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            if (this.canExecute != null)
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }
    }
```

In my references, I just have Windows Phone and .Net for Windows Phone

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that you've already added the `using System.Windows.Input` , then try adding `PresentationCore` within your `References`.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16950813/class-library-does-not-recognize-commandmanager-class)

Comment: Thanks, when i go on the object explorer, when I click on the reference, I have the CommandManager inside the System.Windows.Input class wich is inside the PresentationCore :(. I wanted to put a picture but i dont have enough reputation.